# I can't pass the request value to controller laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, request, laravel-8

Hi I'm new to Laravel and I'm having problem in passing the request properly in my controller which is a resource for update function I'm using Laravel 8. there is no error with the syntax it just return the request is empty. I paste my code for references.

my **AJAX Request**

```
    let url = '/companystructure/1';
$.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                    });
        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            type: "PATCH",
                            data: {
                                'fullname' : 'albert'
                            },
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                                
                                //alert(response);
                                //location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                var error = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText) || thrownError;
                                var errorMsg = error['message'] || thrownError;
                                var errorObj = error.errors || [];
                                if (errorObj) {
                                    Object.keys(errorObj).forEach(function (key){
                                        if (errorObj[key][0].length <= 1 ) {
                                        errorMsg = errorMsg + '<br/>' + errorObj[key];
                                        } else {
                                        errorMsg = errorMsg + '<br/>' + errorObj[key][0];
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                md.showNotification(errorMsg, 'danger');
                            }
                        });
```

and here is **controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    return response()->json($request);
}
```

and here is my **Route**

```
Route::resource('companystructure', CompanyStructureController::class);
```

this is the return I receive from my controller

[image]

Comment: what is your `Content-Type` in header ?

Comment: I don't have content-type

Comment: You can check Your Ajax request like `Request::ajax()` what's its ouptut??

Comment: the return for that is "TRUE"

Comment: I also try it on the regular form where the page is load and it works perfect but the Request::ajax() return is false

Comment: maybe my request should have more header parameter?

Answer (score 0):

type: 'PATCH' does not exists on HTTP methods thus will not be recognized by Laravel.
Try this:

```
      let url = '/companystructure/1';
$.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                    });
        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            type: "POST", /// UPDATE
                            data: {
                                'fullname' : 'albert',
                                '_method': 'PATCH',   /// UPDATE
                            },
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                                
                                //alert(response);
                                //location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                var error = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText) || thrownError;
                                var errorMsg = error['message'] || thrownError;
                                var errorObj = error.errors || [];
                                if (errorObj) {
                                    Object.keys(errorObj).forEach(function (key){
                                        if (errorObj[key][0].length <= 1 ) {
                                        errorMsg = errorMsg + '<br/>' + errorObj[key];
                                        } else {
                                        errorMsg = errorMsg + '<br/>' + errorObj[key][0];
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                md.showNotification(errorMsg, 'danger');
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: if I change on post i receive this error


The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

Comment: do you have an earlier route in your routes file that could be catching this?

Comment: also make sure that you are entering update() method by dd('landing')

Comment: how will make that I landing on update

Comment: yah I land on function update, when i use different function not in resource it works fine